# include blade (nav blade) not working as expected, navbar overrides yield content

Tags: php, css, laravel, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have 3 elements in main view

1. header (navbar)
2. content
3. footer

in app.blade.php

```
    @include('header')    

    <main role="main" class="container">
      @yield('content')
    </main>

    @include('inc.footer')
```

It works fine but the navbar seems to be not part of the page, it doesn't have its own hight, instead it stands on top of the next element.

please consider I'm new to Laravel.

before hiding navabar: 
https://ibb.co/mDsbsw2

after hiding navbar: https://ibb.co/7Y3h28R

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes because you are just including you blade not extends so try to **extend** your yield where it placed.

And place it in correct order.
Hope this helps :)